# Compare length of string in regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't have much knowledge about working of regex but I have been trying to solve this from last many hours but could not get solution of it`.

```
regex  /^[]{13,17}$/i
```

I have a text-box and text-box value should be greater than or equal to 13 and less than or equal to 17.

> Ex.

```js
var value - "12345678901234".(textbox value and length is 14)
if (value.match(regex)) {
  alert("Correct value");
} else {
  alert("error");
}
```

Now, length is 14, it means condition should be true. But match function always return `null`. I have tried also test function, but it doesn't give desired result.

Comment: Use `^.{13,17}$`. `[]` means *nothing*.

Comment: Hi Wiktor. This regex is coming from database and it's creating dynamically. In subscript, sometimes value can't be blank.

Comment: Then you have to replace dynamically `[]` by `.` ; check `alert("1234567890123".match( /^[]{13,17}$/i) + " " + "1234567890123".match( /^.{13,17}$/i))` and you will see the difference.

Comment: This online regex expression builder might help.  It displays errors and provides expression hints: [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: If you actually mean *any character*, then you must replace `[]` with `[^]` or `[\s\S]`. Can you replace each `[]` with `[\s\S]`/`[^]`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I am not getting you completely. Can you please elaborate it. Your first comments works proper. But i can't leave subscript in regex. Sometimes value can come in this.

Comment: What is *subscript*?

Comment: I mean this brackets - []

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Can you post a answer, How can i solve this in professional way like by replacing or any other.

Comment: You need to write a parser for a regex - that requires some effort. If you offer a bounty, I think there will be more volunteers to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102991/discussion-between-puneet-chawla-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2):

You should specify which kind of characters has to be in the sequence:

Any character-

```
/^.{13,17}$/i
```

Digits -

```
/^[0-9]{13,17}$/i
```

Letters -

```
/^[A-Z]{13,17}$/i
```

letters, digits, underscore and dash -

```
/^[A-Z0-9_-]{13,17}$/i
```

Comment: Hi Puneet - I agree with other comment contributions - if that regular expression is given, you need to change it dynamically (sorry, but when I started answering there was no comment).

Comment: Okay. Can you please update your question with specifying how can i change it dynamically.

Comment: I am not sure about your case, but you can convert the regexp to a string (`toString()`), strip the leading '/' and trailing '/i' away, then replace the squares with a dot `replace( "[]", "." )` and eventually convert the string back to regexp  (`new RegExp( str, "i" )`)

Comment: It also doesn't work - Any character -   /^.{13,17}$/i. Only this work               ^.{13,17}$  but can't use this.

Comment: I think you are mixing strings (`"abc"`) and regexp (`/abc/`) concepts. If you invoke `match` with a string, then no slashes are needed, but if you use a regexp, then slashes are needed because they are the delimiters for the regexp itself. You can switch back and forth between regexp and string as I wrote in my comment above.